# Confusion in ROS2 default middleware

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have noted that FastRTPS is the default middleware in ROS2 Foxy.
But again, there are 2 version of FastRTPS too: a) FastRTPS dynamic (rmw_fastrtps_dynamic_cpp)  and b) Plain FastRTPS (rmw_fastrtps_cpp).

So which one exactly is the default middleware in ROS 2 Foxy Fitzroy ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369164/confusion-in-ros2-default-middleware/) by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2021-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default for Foxy Fitzroy is `rmw_fastrtps_cpp`.

It is the first one listed on [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#foxy-fitzroy-may-2020-may-2023).

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2021-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aakashp](https://answers.ros.org/users/57188/aakashp/) on 2021-01-10**:
Thank you @jacobperron